# Reading Excel file based on 2 conditions in Pythton 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4, openpyxl

I have a excel file that has 5 columns holding player data.

column A: Player name, Column B: Team:, Column C: points, column D, Cost, Column E: position.

I know how to get the price of the player by entering the player name as follows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

print ("Going to execute the Player Choices")

total = {}
for player in range(4):

```
player = input("Enter player name")
wb = load_workbook("LeaguePlayers.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
for cell in ws.columns[0]: # get first column
    if cell.value == player:
        cost = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value
        position = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value
        print("{0} ({2}) costs {1}".format(player, cost, position))

        total[player] = cost
        break
print("Total Spend is: ",sum(total.values()),"Million")


print ("End of player choices")
print(total)
```

What I want to know is how is it possible to get a players price if the player I have searched for is position "Midfielder" from column E. So just to be clear If I want to get a price for a midfielder and I type Rooney it should look in column E and realise this is not a midfielder and prompt me to enter again until I enter a player who is a midfielder and the price is then displayed.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the best solution to this problem is to take the data from Excel and put it in a database which you can then query. Alternatively, you might want to query the data with Excel using the excellent [xlwings](http://xlwings.org).

Comment: I have had a look at the link to xlwings but it doesnt show how i can get data from a table in access if i was to put my excel data in to a one table database in access. Can you point me to a link that shows how i can query an access database using python. Thanks. I'm looking but cannot find anything appropriate.

Comment: ...Or is there a way that i can pull all of the data in to a dictionary and then somehow extract the data based on 2 conditions(player name + position).

Comment: I would suggest you use an in memory database using the sqlite module of Python. You just need to create a schema and insert the data row by row. Then you can query it. No need for MS Access. The documentation of the standard library and openpyxl give you all the information you need.

Comment: I have 500+ rows in my excel to manually add them to my schema in sqlite will take ages to type in the code

Comment: Why on earth would you want to add data manually? Loop over the rows in openpyxl and insert them into a suitable sqlite table. Please refer to the documentation for further details as you need to know is covered there.

Comment: which version of sqlite is the best for python 3.4. Whilst I'm at it are there other useful modules that work well with sqlite?

Comment: Python comes with sqlite. `import sqlite3`